# Displaying multiple price for products

Tags: 7, entities, commerce

I'm trying to create two selling price for each products. One is retail and another is wholesale price. For that I have two price fields in my product variation (`commerce_price` and `wholesale price`). But when I add a product it was displaying only `commerce_price`. I want to display both prices. I have enabled both price fields in its `display settings` also.

Here is the snapshot how it was looking now
[image: Here is the snapshot how it was looking now]

Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this?

Comment: If you are using a contributed them, then the template file which is printing the product could be the culprit. Take a look at that.

Comment: @GokulNK there is no code related to the product price in template file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using commerce kickstart and/or you've got [Commerce Extra Price Formatters](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_extra_price_formatters) installed, it has an extension that provides the feature you're displaying, RRPP and your price.

Check out your display options, the second price won't appear automatically until you make it so. Go to `admin/structure/types/manage/[your-product-machine-name]/display` and verify that your price is being displayed there:

[image]

Then click in the link for the settings of the variation type display if you're in kickstart or go to `admin/commerce/config/product-variation-types` and edit the display for your variation type.

[image]

If you're not in kickstart, the url for this same screen would be `admin/commerce/products/types`

Change the price formatter to `Formatted price` or whatever other fits for your needs.

Comment: Thank you pcambra. I really missed to enable it in content type. I have one more question on this. I have provide two radio buttons for the buyers, they can select either `retail` or `wholesale`. I need to change the price in the cart based on their selection. Is there any `hook` provides access to change the price.

Comment: I think you should make another question for that, not really related.

Comment: OK then, I'll post a new question soon. Thanks for your help